# How is it possible to use fmincon to set a variable to zero if a functional inequality constraint is not satisfied?

Tags: matlab, optimization, constraints, mathematical-optimization

I want to set a constraint to the variable `x(1)` by using function `f(x)` and given a constant `a`. How can I build it by using `fmincon`?

```
if  f(a)>=x(1) then x(1)=0
```

In addition, I have also lower and upper boundary conditions:

```
0<=x(1)<=f(b) %given b
```